# Way to find eigen value of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

The diagonal entries of a triangular matrix are the Eigen values of the matrix as per the theorm.
My question is why not convert the given ordinary matrix into a triangular one by row reducing it and now the diagonal entries will be the Eigen values of the matrix

Comment: The reason is that performing an elementary row operation will usually change the eigenvalues of the matrix.

Comment: That would possibly violate the [Abel-Ruffini theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem).

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Even worse: roots of a rational polynomials would always be rational numbers. Just take its companion matrix!

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut True. Thanks for the comment. That covers even $2\times 2$ matrices.

Answer (score 2):

Row reducing will in general change the eigenvalues of a matrix: Consider the following example: 
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2\\ 2 & 1\end{pmatrix} $$
The characteristic polynomial is
$$ \chi_A(\lambda) = (1-\lambda)^2 - 4 = \lambda^2 - 2\lambda - 3 = (\lambda + 1)(\lambda - 3) $$
Hence the eigenvalues are $\lambda = -1, 3$.

Row reducing gives 
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2\\ 2 & 1\end{pmatrix} \to \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 2 \\ 0 & -3 \end{pmatrix} $$
The eigenvalues of the reduced matrix are $1$ and $-3$.

Answer (score 0):

Because elementary row operations will often change the eigenvalues.